# How do you capitalize the first two letters

Tags: python, string

I have usernames that are in this format RSmith. I can put them in all upercase or Title them to look like this, Rsmith, but I need RSmith.

current script:

```
import csv

app_csv = ('/tmp/lowerAccounts.csv')
app_csv_upper = ('/tmp/Identity_Accounts.csv')
in_app_csv = open(app_csv)
out_app_csv = open(app_csv_upper, 'w')
inreader = csv.reader(in_app_csv)
outwriter = csv.writer(out_app_csv)
for row in inreader:
    outwriter.writerow(row)
    row[0] = row[0].upper()
    outwriter.writerow(row)
    row[0] = row[0].title(row)
    outwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: If the answer below helped solve your question, please consider accepting it!

Answer (score 19):

You can use basic string slicing:

```
s = 'rsmith'
s = s[:2].upper() + s[2:]
print(s)
```

Output:

```
RSmith
```

Comment: this seems to be the simpler & the faster way to do that. and it doesn't even break if the string is 1 char long... well done.

Comment: This worked!!...will have to get better at python slicing